# I want to get rid of the sentence “posts tagged _____” on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, html, css, customization

I have created a photography Tumblr site to showcase my work: http://wonryu93.tumblr.com I love the theme and its simple grid system but! the redirected pages show the sentence "posts tagged _" on the top left causing the grid to be broken.

I was hoping there would be a way to either delete this so that everything is flush like the home page, or at least move it above or below the grid so that it wouldn't affect the grid system. I am new to the HTML, CSS thing so it would be great if you could explain thoroughly!

Again, I am talking about the actual sentence visible on my blog: I want to make it invisible, not the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the specific sentence "posts tagged *_*" is generated within the `{block:TagPage}{/block:TagPage}` blocks, and so if you want to remove that, simply find and remove the line in your theme's code enclosed by those particular tags.

For the current theme *you're* using, the specific line of code to remove would be something like

`{block:TagPage} <article class="alert"> <p class="results">{lang:Showing posts tagged Tag 3}</p> </article> {/block:TagPage}`

You can do so by pulling up your custom HTML and Ctrl + F to search and replace that line/elements in that line.

For anyone who also wishes to do so with a different theme, try to search up the `{block:TagPage}{/block:TagPage}` blocks and remove them along with any code enclosed within.

---

<kbd>{block:TagPage} {/block:TagPage}</kbd><kbd>Rendered on tag pages.</kbd> -
[Creating a custom HTML theme | Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tag-pages)

Comment: EXACTLY EXACTLY what i needed.

Comment: worked like magic. Thank you so so so so so so much.